# Update Document with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Well i'm trying to swap for MonogDB but i facing a dumb question here with PYMONGO, and i arealdy tried several things here and already spend a half of my day trying to figure out how to solve this question.

As i said above it's a basic doubt about CRUD operation,  where I'm trying to update a document over MongoDB.

The structure from the document inside the database is that:

```
{
_id: 123456,
key_stock: '756159'
stock: 'abc',
code: 'cba',
qrtly_result: {
      '30/01/2000': {
           'item1': '123',
           'item2': '321',
           'item3': '987',
           }
      }
}
```

Then i trying to update this document this way:

```
# Connect @ DB:
client = MongoClient(connect_db.uri)
db = client.get_database(connect_db.data_base)
collection = db[connect_db.collection]


# New DICT
result = {
   '30/09/2020':{
       'item1': '123',
       'item2': '321',
       'item3': '987',
   },
   '30/06/2020':{
       'item1': '123',
       'item2': '321',
       'item3': '987',
   },    
}



# Update @ DB:
collection.update_one(
    {'key_stock': 756159},
    {'$set': {'qrtly_result': result}}
)


# If i use this way all doc going to root of the document
# but i need this new dict go for "qrtly_results"


collection.update_one(
    {'key_stock': 756159},
    {'$set': 'result'}
)
```

Any suggestion how to solve this ?

Regard's,
Felipe Cid

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by `If i use this way all doc going to root of the document but i need this new dict go for "qrtly_results"`. Please post the result and your expected result. First problem is your match clause in `collection.update_one`. The code matches `"key_stock": 756159` but the document has `"key_stock": "756189"`, data type matters.

Answer (score 0):

First thing it's that `key_stock` is a string in your database, but it's an int in your update query. the type is important to match variables

If you want to replace the `qrtly_result`, fixing the data type will work with work. try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NmURQpvslCA)

But, If you want to add values to `qrtly_result`, your query should look like something like this :

```
db.collection.update({
  "key_stock": 756159
},
{
  "$set": {
    "qrtly_result.30/09/2020": {
      "item1": "123",
      "item2": "321",
      "item3": "987",
      
    },
    "qrtly_result.30/06/2020": {
      "item1": "123",
      "item2": "321",
      "item3": "987",
      
    }
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RWKhfyhqwHa)